# In Windows' cmd.exe shell, how can I pipe the output of a Perl script to a Python script?

Tags: python, perl, cmd

Let's say I have an example `perl` program, that I can run from CMD (Windows 7) using the command:

```
perl hello.pl
```

This outputs:

```
Hello World!
```

I can place this in a file using:

```
perl hello.pl > output.txt
```

However, what I would like to do, is give it to another application, for this I need it to be fed to a Python application.  I give arguments to my Python application using the syntax:

```
python python.py Arg1 Arg2 Arg3
```

Assuming my Perl program only gives one parameter, is there a way to run a Python application once it has finished with this parameter?

Comment: Not a duplicate, none of the questions work because I am working with CMD.  At least, none of the three answers given there work

Comment: Make your python program read the output from the perl program from `sys.stdin` and pipe the perl program's `stdout` to it: `perl hello.pl | python python.py Arg1 Arg2 Arg3`

Comment: Wait, you are able to pipe in cmd?  Okay, thanks for the solution.  Considering this is a duplicate, should I delete?

Comment: @martineau I re-opened the question so you can turn your comment into an answer. @Popey: Of course you can pipe in `cmd` ... Where have you been?

Comment: Worked for me in cmd console but from one python program to another (I don't have perl installed).

Comment: Hm, it did work, thanks @martineau - @ Sinan, I've been living in a place without cmd =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your python program read the output from the perl program from `sys.stdin` and pipe the perl program's stdout to it:

```
perl hello.pl | python python.py Arg1 Arg2 Arg3
```

I tested this going from one python program to another and in the second python program just did:

```
import sys

inp = sys.stdin.readline()
print(inp)
```